# Updating multiple attributes within one put route

Tags: mongodb, backbone.js, mongoose

So far I had to update only the name of my model but now I need to update some more attributes:

```
.put(function(req, res){
    Task.findById(req.params.task_id, function(err, task){
        if(err)
            res.send(err)

        task.name = req.body.name;

        task.save(function(err,bear){
            if(err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(task)
        });
    });
})
```

How can I handle all the updates without adding this line `task.attr = req.body.attr`
for each attribute?

Comment: If things were working properly the model would automatically update with the json response from the server

Answer (score 2):

You can update model by using

```
model.set(attributes, [options]) 

 Ex :model.set({name: "yourName", desc: "In his eyes she eclipses..."});
```

Comment: updating the model backbone is not the problem, the problem is saving the attributes on the server model, which is mongodb doc.
as you see in my code i saving the name only but i want to save all the attributes without adding  a line for each attr